# Search for the newest file in several random folders and copy it to network location

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Inside folder C:\Temp\2019 I have backup folders named by current date (1,2,3, etc that contain the same data from different dates), and inside that is folders named by the project. I'm trying to create a script that can find the newest file named test.txt that can be found in one of the project folders (1,2,3,etc) and copy it to network location \nettest\temp\backup. Every single folder.

I try to create some robocopy script that can resolve my problem or batch script, but my problem is that search only main folder, and I need to find a way to include all subfolders whatever they are named.

```
@echo off
set Location=C:\Temp\2019
Set Destination=\\nettest\temp\backup
Set FileName=*test.txt*
Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
Where /R "%Location%" "%FileName%" > %SearchResult%
For /f "delims=*" %%a in (%SearchResult%) Do (If Not Exist "%Destination%\%%~na" MD "%Destination%\%%~na")
For /f "delims=*" %%b in (%SearchResult%) Do (echo Copy "%%b" "%Destination%\%%~nb" & Copy /-Y "%%b" "%Destination%\%%~nb")
pause
Explorer "%Destination%"
```

My problem with this code I try is because it searches only one directorial, and I need it to include every single one subdirectory.

Comment: Why did you include the PowerShell tag when you are doing it via bat?

Comment: It looks like you should be using Version Control. Take a look at git. It's free and it allows you to sync your local repository with your "backup" repository on your network location.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh because I'm tyred to create robocopy script as well that can be started using cmd or PowerShell as well, so I'm open for an alternative solution to this problem if there is one.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers tnx Lieven, I'm going to look into git, but I think that is not the solution what I need. I'm looking for a solution that can be easily applied for sync from one network location to another one too, and can be scheduled to do it once per day in spec. time.

Comment: Well, you can try following Powershell `gci c:\temp\2019\*test.txt* -rec -file | sort lastwritetime -desc | select -first 1 | % {copy -path $_ -destination($_.fullname -replace 'c:\\temp\2019', '\\nettest\temp\backup') -force -whatif}`. Remove the `-whatif` to actualy perform the copy.

Comment: Thank you @LievenKeersmaekers I think that can solve my issue. :)

Comment: Please be aware that your question did not mention including any files directly contained within `c:\temp\2019`, just those of its subdirectories. If you  could potentially have files of matching pattern in that parent directory, you'd need to modify the [tag:powershell] code to exclude them.